# Fixing rows offset in some rows in ssis?

Tags: c#, sql, ssis

I am working on a package where I have to load data that looks like this

| StudentID | Class | SignUpDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Math 101 | 01/09/2020 |
| 2 | Math 102 | 01/09/2020 |

the problem is that I have few rows that are not in the right place, so I'm seeing the date data is coming in the class column, and this is happening only in some of the rows not always.
heres a sample of the faulty rows

| StudentID | Class | SignUpDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Math 101 |  |
|  | 01/09/2020 |  |

I tried to error output the wrong data into another CSV then merge them together but I couldn't link the wrong data to the correct rows with no common column
is there any possible way to fix this using SSIS?

Comment: What do you mean by "the problem is that I have few rows that are not in the right place" ? Can you share a sample of your CSV file and the configuration of the source?

Comment: I mean the information inside some rows is not in the right column, like you see in the sample table I created the SignUpDate Infos are in the following Class column. this is happening only in few rows, while most of the other rows look fine and in the right place. I was thinking it's a delimiter problem but it's not since it's happening to only a few rows.

Comment: What component you are using for the source?

Answer (score 0):

Try making the rows in table as not null then it may give error and these rows will be directed to error output. Also can you please provide some sample dummy source data